# How to write query menus and submenus n level using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, menuitem, submenu

I have SQL Server 2008 table `MenuItem` in following format.

```
 MenuItemsID     MenuType     ItemsName  ParentID     URL          Images

       1            1           Home         0         --            ---
       2            1          Product       0         ---           ----
       3            1          Catagories    0         ---            ----
       4            1          Brand         0         Brand.aspx     ----
       5            1          H1            1         ------          -----
       6            1          H2            1         ------        --------
       7            1          P1            2         ----           ------
       8            1          c1            3         ----           ---
       9            1          H1Submneu1    5         ---               ----
       10           1           P1 subMenu   7         -------           ---
```

like that

I have tried to write a query to retrieve up to one level of submenus

```
select 
    m.ItemName, STUFF((select ',' + s.ItemName 
                       from MenuItems s
                       where s.ParentId = m.MenuItemsID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as SubMenus
from MenuItems m 
where ParentId = 0
```

But I want m levels of submenues

How to could be write that query? Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need a recursive CTE (Common Table Expression) to achieve this. Try something like this:

```
;WITH Submenus AS
(
    SELECT 
        MenuItemID, ItemsName, ParentID, Level = 0
    FROM
        dbo.menuitem m
    WHERE
        m.ParentID = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        m2.MenuItemID, m2.ItemsName, m2.ParentID, s.Level + 1 
    FROM
        dbo.menuitem m2
    INNER JOIN
        Submenus s ON m2.ParentID = s.MenuItemID  
)  
SELECT
    *
FROM    
    Submenus
ORDER BY
    Level, MenuItemID
```

This gives me an output of:

```
MenuItemID  ItemsName  ParentID  Level
   1        Home           0       0
   2        Product        0       0
   3        Categories     0       0
   4        Brand          0       0
   5        H1             1       1
   6        H2             1       1
   7        P1             2       1
   8        C1             3       1
   9        H1Sub1         5       2
  10        P1Sub1         7       2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive CTEs:

```
;WITH cte_menu(Level, MenuItemsId, MenuType, ItemsName, ParentID, URL, Images)
AS
(
SELECT 0 AS Level, MenuItemsId, MenuType, ItemsName, ParentID, URL, Images
FROM MenuItem 
WHERE ParentID = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT Level + 1, t.MenuItemsId, t.MenuType, t.ItemsName, t.ParentID, t.URL, t.Images
FROM MenuItem  t
INNER JOIN cte_menu c ON c.MenuItemsId = t.ParentID
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_menu
ORDER BY Level, MenuItemsId
```

[More on Recursive Queries Using CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: @jaime...Actully i am bind the menu and submenus of sumneus like...how to pass the values

Comment: @RaghuBandaru sorry, I don't understand what You mean. Could You explain?

Comment: @jaime...am building Menus And submenus..like shopping website "http://www.myntra.com/" in website MEN,Women Kids,BRands like am also building from database... so am using Asp.net WebApi so can u help me please..........